# How do I get the value for a variable in shell script where its name is partially substituted from another variable?

Tags: shell

For example, I have below in a script. I expect the output from echo to be 5, but I get demo. Can someone help me with the correct syntax?

```
C_id_demo=5
var1="demo"
echo $C_id_${var1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` for this:

```sh
eval echo \$C_id_${var1}
```

Note 1: the `\` is there for the full variable is evaluated by the `echo`, not the `eval`.

Note 2: usage of `eval` may be dangerous. Be sure that you really know what is in the evaluated variable.